# Symmetric functions for a subgroup of permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, symmetric-groups

It is a well-known theorem that the ring of polynomials $P \in \mathbb{C}[x_1 , \dots , x_n]$ that are invariant under all the permutations $\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}_n$ is in fact $\mathbb{C}[e_1 , \dots ,e_n]$ where the $e_i$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials, that can be seen as being generated by
$$(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\dots (x-x_n). $$
We write this as
$$ \mathbb{C}[x_1 , \dots , x_n]^{\mathfrak{S}_n} = \mathbb{C}[e_1 , \dots e_n]. $$

Consider a subgroup $G \subset \mathfrak{S}_n$.
**Is there a similar description of the ring of polynomials that are invariant under $G$ ?**

By similar, I mean the following: is it possible to find explicitly a minimal finite set of polynomials $f_1 , \dots , f_r \in \mathbb{C}[x_1 , \dots , x_n]$ such that
$$ \mathbb{C}[x_1 , \dots , x_n]^G = \mathbb{C}[f_1 , \dots , f_r] ? $$
It is known (see for instance [here](https://math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/pubs/pubfiles/38.pdf), theorem 1.2) that $r$ can be chosen smaller than $\frac{(g+n)!}{g!n!}$ where $g=|G|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by similar description. There is always a finite set of invariant polynomials such that all invariant polynomials are *consequences* of these being invariant. That is they are generated as ring by these.

However the invariants cannot be expected to be algebraically independent.
A necessary and sufficient condition for this to happen is the subgroup be generated by reflections: that is in the linear span of $x_i$'s the representation of this subgroup should be generated by (pseudo) reflections. 
The sufficiency was proved by Chevalley, and necessity by Shepherd-Todd. See book by Humphreys, or Kane, or Kemper.

EDIT: for computational aspects see the books by Kemper & Derksen, or the book by Sturmfels (Algorithmic Invariant Theory)

Comment: I have edited the question to be more precise. I'm looking for a way to compute the $f_i$.